# Is it advisable to update to Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04

I use ubuntu 15.10 on my HP laptop with AMD Radeon Graphic card. And I have read that ubuntu 16.04 doesn't support this graphic cards. Is it true still? 
Also, how advisable is it to update from 15.10 to 16.04 considering ubuntu no longer updates 15.10? How buggy is 16.04, and what problems may I expect?

Comment: You should not `upgrade` until you've thoroughly researched the AMD issues. There are lots of questions and answers on this topic in askubuntu so searching here for all you can find (in the last few months only) is a good idea. It would be best if you setup a test partition solely for the purpose of trying out the new release before upgrading for real.

Comment: Thank you, I am looking into more answers already, but most of the questions seem to have made months ago. I was wondering if the situation has changed in any way. Also, regardless of the graphic card, How stable is Xenial Xerus? Is the software center bug fixed?